# What does "steenking" mean?

Tags: single-word-requests, orthography

I read some source code and came across this sentence:

> Hopefully it works, and we don't need no steenking BIOS anyway [...]

You see the word "steenking" in there. I traced its origin down to the phrase ["We don't need no stinking badges"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stinking_badges) but still don't know why anyone would write "stinking" as "steenking."

Could anyone explain this weird spelling?

Comment: Maybe it's for emphasis. Maybe typo. Maybe an accent.

Comment: For further reading (be warned- TV Tropes link): [Funetik Aksent](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FunetikAksent)

Comment: @cobaltduck The official term is "[eye dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_dialect)".

Comment: It's an intentional mispronunciation (a la a Mexican dialect) of "stinking".

Comment: I wonder what it says about me, that before I had clicked through to read your question I already had that source code comment in mind, and remembered which software it can be [found](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/i386/boot/setup.S?v=2.2.26#L694) in and what the context is... Maybe it is because I haven't seen the spelling "steenking" used anywhere else.

Comment: @Downvoter Why the downvote?

Comment: I wonder if we actually have a member called Downvoter who's very confused right now. Aww, just checked and we don't.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's supposed to be a Mexican accent.

From [the wikipedia article you linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stinking_badges):

> In one scene, a Mexican bandit leader named "Gold Hat" (portrayed by [Alfonso Bedoya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfonso_Bedoya)) tries to convince Fred C. Dobbs ([Humphrey Bogart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humphrey_Bogart)) that he and his company are [Federales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federales):
>
> **Dobbs:** "If you're the police, then where are your badges?"
>
> **Gold Hat:** "Badges? We ain't got no badges. We don't need no badges. I don't have to show you any stinkin' badges!"
>
> Both a 1967 episode of [The Monkees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Monkees_(TV_series)) and Mel Brooks' 1974 [Western](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_(genre)) [Blazing Saddles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blazing_Saddles) misquoted the line as "Badges? We don't need no stinking badges.", and it is this version of the phrase that went on to be quoted, paraphrased, and parodied in a variety of subsequent media.

It's more obvious if you watch the clips in question.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqomZQMZQCQ) is the original clip on YouTube:

[image]

And [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TFwprS_L6tg) is the Blazing Saddles version:

[image]

The "steenking" you found is just the phonetic spelling of the accent used by these actors.

**Note:** Whether this accent is accurate or politically correct or insensitive or funny I leave up to you to decide. But for better or worse, this is what whoever wrote that comment was referencing.

Comment: It's been widely used:

http://www.rudebadmood.com/badges/allindex.shtml

Comment: @Kevin, +1 for the comprehensive answer with excellent real-time edits. :-) Good job!

Comment: That and the "stinking badgers" line from _UHF_.

Comment: I would suspect it's more a reference to Ren from the [The Ren & Stimpy Show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ren_%26_Stimpy_Show), who happened to be a Chihuahua.

Comment: @ArtB What makes you suspect that? Ren (along with many other tv and movie characters) does have a fake Mexican accent, but "we don't need no stinking..." is a pretty popular quote that predates Ren and Stimpy. Obviously we can't be sure without asking the original developer, but I highly doubt it's a reference to Ren and Stimpy. If you disagree, please post your own answer and allow people to debate its merits.

Comment: I read that in Ren's voice, and guestimating the age of the average developer it seems to have been a likely source. No need for separate which is merely a twist to your answer.

Comment: The [CQ Congressional Quarterly](https://books.google.com/books?id=nxmIAAAAMAAJ&q=%22need+no+stinking%22&dq=%22need+no+stinking%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRvfPlmunLAhUlnoMKHfcjAUo4ChDoAQg-MAc) from 1956 includes the line "We don't need no stinking spending cuts."  And, of course, there are many others.  "Don't need no stinking" (with whatever accent you felt appropriate) was a fixture of American jargon well before Ren & Stimpy or BIOS or modern computers.

Comment: @ArtB kasperd pointed out that this comment is in `setup.S` from [the linux kernel](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/i386/boot/setup.S?v=2.0.40) originally written in 1992. People tend to forget that not every developer is a kid with a startup when guesstimating the average developer's age. :p

Comment: A bunch more [youtube references](https://youtu.be/XT8hE7_8BCY).  The final ones are a bit humorous.